# AWS Instance cannot connect after resizing volume and reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am facing connectivity issues with my AWS EC2 instance after resizing its volume. Here's what I did:

I had an EC2 instance running Ubuntu in a container with a full storage.
I modified the volume to a larger size.
Followed the steps in this link

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html[link][1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html%5Blink%5D%5B1%5D)

to resize the disk.
After resizing, I encountered an error while trying to run sudo:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx: Name or service not known
```

A user in a forum suggested that it might be due to the full disk issue, which I had recently faced.

To resolve this, I rebooted the instance from the AWS console. However, after the reboot, I am unable to connect to the instance either through SSH or AWS console connect.

Interestingly, I created a new instance using the same security group, and it works perfectly. But, I still can't connect to the old instance.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably an unhappy operating system. You can use **Actions / Monitor and Troubleshoot / Get system log** in the EC2 management console to see what the operating system is saying during the boot process.

Comment: Try to trouble shoot it with System log and system screenshot as well using **Actions** > **Monitor and Troubleshoot** > Get System log and Get Instance screenshot options